# how to find the xpath for the below code

Tags: selenium, xpath

Trying to find the xpath for the below face book link .

```
    <a class="home_fb_logo" target="_blank" title="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/chaturdn"></a>
    <a class="home_tw_logo" target="_blank" title="twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/chaturdn"></a>
    <a class="home_sc_logo" target="_blank" title="soundcloud" href="http://www.soundcloud.com/chaturdn"></a>
    <a class="home_go_logo" target="_blank" title="google+" href="https://www.google.com/+dnchaturvedi/about"></a>
    <a class="home_yt_logo" target="_blank" title="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/chaturdn"></a>
    <a class="home_li_logo" target="_blank" title="linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/chaturdn"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: which link? i think you forgot something to add

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
 //a[@class='home_fb_logo']
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `//*[@title="facebook"]`

to get the link find the element `//*[@title="facebook"]` and use `getAttribute("href")` to get the link in selenium.

Comment: Be careful with xpath function. As my remembering, selenium doesnot support xpath function. org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException will throw

Comment: where we using functions in the above xpath

Comment: who mentioned it is related to selenium

Comment: please see question's tag

Comment: your xpath is correct. However, when added it into selenium script, exception throws. Have just tested it and here's the result org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[@title='facebook']/@href is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@title='facebook']/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
Command duration or timeout: 55 milliseconds

Comment: yes right. use this //*[@title="facebook"] and use some getAtrribute in selenium

Answer (score 0):

To get a handle on the Facebook `link` WebElement you could use either of the following XPath expressions:

```
//a[@class='home_fb_logo']
//a[@title='facebook']
```

To get the actual URL from the `link` WebElement you can use the WebElement[.getAttribute()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) method like so:

```
String url = element.getAttribute("href");
```